# Not able to connect SharePoint 2010 using SOAP API

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm using reverse proxy concept on the servers in which I am using one public IP for reverse proxy server and rest of servers having internal IPs.

I have installed the SharePoint in one of the server having internal IP and mapped the public DNS with the internal IP on reverse proxy server. When I am tyring to access the sharepoint using FQDN from browser then I am able to access but when I am trying use using SOAP API then it throws an error.

Why it is autmatically picking the internal IP (rather than FQDN) while executing the SOAP API?

Where can I configure the FQDN on Sharepoint so that it can pick the FQDN instead of IP?

> Mon Jan 25 17:56:16 GMT 2016:ERROR:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://10.25.218.12 refused